# How to show only the text not with HTML content on dropdown menu while filter on handsontable?

Tags: javascript, html, handsontable

How to get rid of rendering HTML content on the dropdown menu while filtering? If the cell or whole column's cell contains HTML data, when we apply the filter, in the dropdown list it is displayed as HTML content, 
How do we show only the text not with HTML content while filter?

This fiddle contains example (in the first columns)

```
var dataObj = [
    ['<a>Lorem</a>', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', '12/1/2015', 23],
    ['<a>adipiscing</a>', 'elit', 'Ut', 'imperdiet', '5/12/2015', 6],
    ['<a>Pellentesque</a>', 'vulputate', 'leo', 'semper', '10/23/2015', 26],
    ['<a>diam</a>', 'et', 'malesuada', 'libero', '12/1/2014', 98],
    ['<a>orci</a>', 'et', 'dignissim', 'hendrerit', '12/1/2016', 8.5]
  ];
  var example1 = document.getElementById('example1');

  var hot = new Handsontable(example1, {
    data: dataObj,
    columns: [
      {type: 'text', renderer: 'html'},
      {type: 'text'},
      {type: 'text'},
      {type: 'text'},
      {type: 'date', dateFormat: 'M/D/YYYY'},
      {type: 'numeric'}
    ],
    colHeaders: true,
    rowHeaders: true,
    dropdownMenu: true,
    dropdownMenu: ['filter_by_value', 'filter_action_bar'],
    filters: true
  });
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/subashdbc/fbtp6dxm/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Handsontable initialiser should be changed to -:

```
function firstColRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
  Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
  td.innerHTML = value.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
}
var hot = new Handsontable(example1, {
    data: dataObj,
    columns: [
      {type: 'text', renderer: 'html'},
      {type: 'text'},
      {type: 'text'},
      {type: 'text'},
      {type: 'date', dateFormat: 'M/D/YYYY'},
      {type: 'numeric'}
    ],
    colHeaders: true,
    rowHeaders: true,
    dropdownMenu: true,
    dropdownMenu: ['filter_by_value', 'filter_action_bar'],
    filters: true,
    cells: function (row, col) {
      var cellProperties = {};
      var data = this.instance.getData();

      if (col === 0) {
        cellProperties.renderer = firstColRenderer; // uses function directly
      }
      return cellProperties;
    }
  });
```

Comment: thanks. But the drop-down menu content on the filter is displaying with HTML content as previous.